# how to install geopandas properly

Tags: python, pip, geopandas

tried most of the solutions around but still could not install geopandas properly on my device.

some of the errors ım getting

- ERROR: Failed building wheel for fiona
- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:Check the logs for full
  command output. FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'geos_c.dll'
  (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with
  constructor syntax.
- A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config
  using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION
  environment variable.

it is trying to find older version over and over for the packages but at the end, geopandas is not getting installed.

tried in different users and text editors.

Comment: Have you consulted documentation? https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html How do you try installing it, which OS? We cannot help without details.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mess for me to succed installing geopandas too. I had to **create a new environment** (check how [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)), **install manually** part of geopandas dependencies, like pandas, shapely and fiona, and then install geopandas (**version 0.10.2**) through pip (it wasn't available at conda).

I know other people who managed to install it just followin [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp3_vEMYoaY&ab_channel=HatariLabs) video tutorial instructions, after downgrading Python from 3.9 version to a lower one.

Good luck!